# Mathematical operation on nember of type string

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

This is what I am curious to know

we have,

```
string Number = "1";
```

How can I add **1** to the value of `Number` such as `1+1=2` in the most simple way other than converting this to an **int**, adding to it and then back to the **string** which will take 3 lines of code. Any LINQ or similar method to do this on the fly?

Comment: Are you asking for a one liner? Because if you have a string you need to do the conversion in any form anyway...

Comment: Your code example is invalid. You should use or `var` keyword or type `string`.

Comment: Converting, adding and reconverting *is* the most simple way. LINQ is not a magic wand that does everything in one line. If you want to work with strings only you need a formula parser like Python.

Comment: sorry for the typo Alexander. i was just fast typing. and generally I wanted to refine my coding skill. it might sound a basic question but everyday i see better ways of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is you cannot have "var" before string either "string" should be present or "var" should be present.

```
var string Number = "1";
```

You can make use of a static method ToInt16() to convert your string to int.
here is the sample code

```
  string Number = "1";
  int result =Convert.ToInt16(Number) + Convert.ToInt16(Number);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Well, this is exactly what the OP asked not to do. (For whatever reason)

Comment: Thanks anyways guys. I think I found out my curiosity to refine the code is irrelevant. I appreciate all the answers and comments. all answers and comments.